# Forward to the right shop depending on products

Tags: multistore

We have the following configuration:

1. [gp] Shop 1

   - [gp-de]German
2. [sh] Shop 2

   - [sh-de]German
3. [bs] Shop 3

   - [bs-de]German

We have three different Shops, but want our customers to be able to mix their products from all shops into one cart and be able to checkout with that single cart. All three shops are under one website. This works perfectly. If you walk through one shop (e.g. via search), you see products from other shops, witch is desired, too. When you click on an product of another shop, you see it with the template and design of the the originating product/page.

We would like to have a switch, which changes the store&store-view and forwards to the domain of the store of the product which is requested.

For example:

- Origin: Form Product 1 of Shop 1
- Click on Product 2 of Shop 2
- --> Show Product 2 in appearance of Shop 2

Is there a possibility to configure this behavior in magento?